# Moving text file and type conversion in command line

Tags: windows, unix, text, cmd

I need to convert multiple UNIX files to PC and move them to a specific folder, without keeping the original UNIX file.

I tested the commands below and they worked, but the TYPE command keeps the original UNIX file and creates a separate PC file.

```
C:\  TYPE input_filename | MORE /P > output_filename  <<< command to conver unix to ansi, works perfect.

C:\ move c:\users\you\somefile.txt   c:\temp\newlocation.txt <<< move a file to another location, work perfect.
```

I would like know if there's a way to use the TYPE and MOVE command together, something similar to this:

```
C:\move c:\users\you\somefile.txt TYPE MORE /P >c:\temp\newlocation.txt
```

So basically it would move the UNIX file to another directory while changing its format to windows.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't, as the third step, use the `del` command on the original file?

Comment: Its kinda hard to explain but this is whats happing..

Comment: I currently have it to 'del' but some files are being lost because that folder is receiving many unix text file, so when a text file converted to another directory the original is scheduled to delete but while the delete is happening it will delete everything that's coming in without begin converted and moved to the other directory. I would say its a timing  issue.

Comment: So that why I ask if its possible for to move and convert at the same time.

Comment: Why is it deleting _everything?_ Surely, you should just be deleting the _specific_ file, no?

Comment: This will be in batch scrip, so the batch  will grab all the text files that in it at that time and just like that it will erase all text files.(There is no specific name for the files the name comes as random numbers)

Thats why im trying to lean towards 'MOVE'. Only if there was a way to move what ever files is in the folder and convert it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cd /d  "c:\users\you\"
for %%i in (*.txt) do (
  echo processing %%i
  TYPE "%%i" | MORE /P > "c:\temp\%%i"
  del "%%i"
)
```

Comment: Can this be in a batch file? and what is %%i?

Comment: yes, it can. `%%i` is a special variable. See `for /?` for an explanation.